# Interpreting the CFI and TLI when RMSEA is lower than 0.158?

Tags: statistics, model-fitting, factor-analysis

When reporting on the absolute fit of a model (for instance a factor model or structure equation model), many different indices are used. Most commonly people report on chi-squared, RMSEA, TLI or CFI. (there are many more)

I have been reading the following on David A. Kenny's website and I was wondering whether someone could explain this to me:

> "A reasonable rule of thumb is to examine the RMSEA (see below) for
>   the null model  and make sure that is no smaller than 0.158. An RMSEA
>   for the model of 0.05 and a TLI of .90, implies that the RMSEA of the
>   null model is 0.158. If the RMSEA for the null model is less than
>   0.158, an incremental measure of fit may not be that informative. So far as I know, this mathematical fact that a model whose null model
>   RMSEA is less than 0.158 and whose RMSEA is 0.05 must have a TLI of
>   less than .90 is something that has never been published but is in
>   fact true. (David A. Kenny: http://davidakenny.net/cm/fit.htm)"

Can someone explain this?

Comment: This question is more appropriate for stats.stackexchange.com. Also, you could try emailing the author to see if he'll explain.

Comment: My apologies, I will try my luck at stat.stackexchange